# Binary Search with Duplicates and not

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, binary

I'm taking a course on Coursera, and I've built two Algorithms for Binary Search, one with duplicates and one without, both arrays are ordered in by largest to smallest number. I've run several tests and they work perfectly in my console, but when I upload them it returns the following for both assignments:

```
Failed case #26/57: Wrong answer

 (Time used: 0.05/5.00, memory used: 41832448/536870912.)
```

It doesn't even give me why it's wrong. I've tried getting a help in the platform but no response.

This is an example input:

```
8  <--- Number of inputs in array
2 4 4 4 7 7 9 <--- Array
4  <---- The quantity of numbers to look for
9 4 7 2 <----- Numbers to look for
```

This is an example output:

```
6 1 4 0 <---- indexes of those number (if duplicates, takes the left most index)
```

If the number is not present, it returns '-1'

This is the Algorithm I built for the duplicates:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false,
});

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
rl.once("line", (line) => {
  const v = parseInt(line, 10);

  rl.once("line", (line) => {
    const array = line.toString().split(" ").map(Number);

    rl.once("line", (line) => {
      const a = parseInt(line, 10);

      rl.once("line", (line) => {
        const list = line.toString().split(" ").map(Number);

        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, 0, v - 1, 0, "");
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});

function binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, high, low, result) {
  let final = result;
  const k = list[count];

  if (count >= a) {
    console.log(final);
  } else {
    if (high < low) {
      binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count + 1, v - 1, 0, final + "-1 ");
    } else {
      let mid = low + Math.floor((high - low) / 2);

      if (k === array[mid]) {
        let index = mid;
        for (i = mid; i <= mid; i--) {
          if (array[i] === k) {
            index = i;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        binarySearch(
          v,
          array,
          a,
          list,
          count + 1,
          v - 1,
          0,
          final + `${index} `
        );
      } else if (k < array[mid]) {
        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, mid - 1, low, final);
      } else {
        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, high, mid + 1, final);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = binarySearch;
```

This is the one without:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  terminal: false,
});

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
rl.once("line", (line) => {
  const v = parseInt(line, 10);

  rl.once("line", (line) => {
    const array = line.toString().split(" ").map(Number);

    rl.once("line", (line) => {
      const a = parseInt(line, 10);

      rl.once("line", (line) => {
        const list = line.toString().split(" ").map(Number);

        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, 0, v - 1, 0, "");
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});

function binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, high, low, result) {
  let final = result;
  let mid = low + Math.round((high - low) / 2);
  const k = list[count];

  if (count === a) {
    console.log(final);
  } else {
    if (high < low) {
      binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count + 1, v - 1, 0, final + "-1 ");
    } else {
      if (k === array[mid]) {
        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count + 1, v - 1, 0, final + `${mid} `);
      } else if (k < array[mid]) {
        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, mid - 1, low, final);
      } else {
        binarySearch(v, array, a, list, count, high, mid + 1, final);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = binarySearch;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that array is sorted in increasing order**

*`The technique to solve which works independently of duplicates in my opinion is to steer to the left half once a match is found in case the left entry is also a valid candidate to expand further on the search`*

```js
function binarySearch(array, val){
    const n = array.length;
    return solve(array,0,n, val);
}

function solve(array, start , end, target){
    while(start < end){
        const mid = Math.floor(start + (end-start)/2);
        if(array[mid] == target){
            if(mid > start && array[mid-1] != target){
                return mid;
            } else {
                end = mid;
            }
        } else if(array[mid] > target){
            end = mid;
        } else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    if(array[start] == target){
        return start;
    }
    return -1;
}

const runTests = () => {
  const cases = [
    {input: [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8], target: 4},
    {input: [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8], target: 6},
    {input: [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8], target: 13},
    {input: [1,2,2,2,4,4,5,6,6,8], target: 2},
    {input: [2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,7,7], target: 7},
    {input: [2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,7,7], target: 5},
    {input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], target: 7},
    {input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], target: 0},
  ];

  cases.forEach(({input,target}) => {
    console.log(binarySearch(input,target));
  });
}

runTests();
```